# How to color an image having shapes?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I know its possible with boundary fill, but have tried everything in Objective C and I'm still not successful. Any help with code will be highly appreciated.

This code returns the color of the touched pixel:

```
unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx);
if (data != NULL) { 
    offset = 4*((w*round(point.y))+round(point.x));
    alpha = data[offset];
    red = data[offset+1];
    green = data[offset+2];
    blue = data[offset+3];
    color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255.0f) green:(green/255.0f) blue:(blue/255.0f) alpha:(alpha/255.0f)];}
```

I am not able to color the pixel, sometimes this code returns different color on the same pixel.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried already so we can help you with a specific problem you're having.

Comment: this code returns me the color of the touched pixel

 unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx);
 if (data != NULL) {
  
  offset = 4*((w*round(point.y))+round(point.x));
  alpha =  data[offset]; 
  red = data[offset+1]; 
  green = data[offset+2]; 
  blue = data[offset+3]; 
  
  color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255.0f) green:(green/255.0f) blue:(blue/255.0f) alpha:(alpha/255.0f)];

but i am not able to color the pixel, sometimes this code returns diff color on same pixel.

Comment: You can click the 'edit' link below the tags and above the comments to edit your question.  I added the code from the comment above, but I'm sure it isn't correct (it's at least missing a "}" and I'm not sure where it goes).  Please edit the post to match the code you're using (copy and paste is best).

Comment: bill its the code which returns the Color of current pixel, i need to have a check on the next pixel if its the same color then do color otherwise don't but i am not able to do that........quite helpless right now :(